# Error undefined is not an object React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state

I have .JSON in this format:

```
{
    "main": {
        "first": {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "abc"
        },
        "second": {
            "id": "321",
            "name": "bca"
        }
    }
}
```

Before I call API I create state this way:

```
const [fetchApiData, setApiData] = useState({main:{}});
```

And I pass my fetchApiData via props to children like:

```
<Index content={fetchApiData}/>
```

But, when I call it in child, error says:

> undefined is not an object!

Child component:

```
<BigNews
id={props.content.main.first.id}
title={props.content.main.first.name}/>
```

Comment: `first.id` and `first.name` are undefined on the first render since you are setting the initial state to `{main:{}}`

Comment: But I have declared main in props... props.content.main.first.id. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Before you render BigNews add a `console.log(props.content)` or put a breakpoint and inspect the props

Comment: This is the result: Object {
  "main": Object {},
}

Comment: But you have not declared `main.first`, so `first` is undefined, and you are trying to access `first.id`, which is the same as `undefined.id` which is the error you are getting

Comment: Exactly what JMadelaine said

Comment: Ok, got it...Is there any way I can avoid this, without declaring first, second.... because I have like hundredth :D

Comment: it's recommended to declare `useState()` than `useState({main:{}});` as latter doesn't make much sense

Comment: If I do this, I get undefined again. Sorry, probably missing something, but I am beginner with React Native.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I have an interface defining the data structure and types, let's call it `JsonStructure`, and then I initialize the state as `useState({} as JsonStructure)`. Then, if I log the whole data object, it logs ok. If I try to access any element of data, I get the error. Do I need the same solution (initializing state with all the properties)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you initial state doesn't have those properties,
Either fill your initial state object :

```
const initialState = {
  "main": {
      "first": {},
      "second": {}
  }
}

const [fetchApiData, setApiData] = useState(initialState);
```

or use [Optional chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)

```
<BigNews
  id={props.content.main.first?.id}
  title={props.content.main.first?.name}/>
```

Comment: is this feature new in es? I know it's there in typescript

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu It is a new feature and it has its own [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), though the compatibility is not that good on mobile yet.

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu it's still experimental but you can use it, using babel plugin which will transpile it to ES5 or ES6 to work accross different browsers

Comment: @EmileBergeron it's still experimental but you can use it, using babel plugin which will transpile it to ES5 or ES6 to work accross different browsers

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't change the link (or asked you to) in your answer, babel is still the safer option right now.